# end='' not working (Python)

Tags: python, line, break

I'm trying to get the output of my program all on one line and when i print "end=''" it doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
import random

thesaurus = {}
with open('thesaurus.txt') as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        synonyms = line.split(',')
        thesaurus[synonyms[0]] = synonyms[1:]

print ("Total words in thesaurus: ", len(thesaurus))

# input
phrase = input("Enter a phrase: ")

# turn input into list
part1 = phrase.split()
part2 = list(part1)


newlist = []
for x in part2:
    s = random.choice(thesaurus[x]) if x in thesaurus else x
    s = random.choice(thesaurus[x]).upper() if x in thesaurus else x
    newlist.append(s)

newphrase = ' '.join(newlist)

print(newphrase, end=' ')
```

Right now, for some reason, my program is printing out :

```
i LOVE FREEDOM
 SUFFICIENCY apples
```

with the input "i like to eat apples"

and the expected output is:

```
 i LOVE FREEDOM SUFFICIENCY apples
```

Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not a problem with `end=''` at all. Lines read from the file still have the newline. When you split the line, the final entry will have a newline as with this example:

```
>>> 'foo,bar,baz\n'.split(',')
['foo', 'bar', 'baz\n']
```

Your problem is that you substituted `"FREEDOM\n"` not just `"FREEDOM"`. Just strip the line before use:

```
thesaurus = {}
with open('thesaurus.txt') as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        synonyms = line.strip().split(',')
        thesaurus[synonyms[0]] = synonyms[1:]
```